# Print directly to the printer via the browser on the tablet, over the web

Tags: printing, android, web, tablet, windows-mobile

I wish to be able to print directly to the printer via the browser on the tablet, over the web. Can I simply get a tablet, connect a USB printer and open Chrome with the --kiosk-printing switch in the same way as one could on a PC?